# how to get the global width and height of movieClip after scaling parent(s)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I do work on some already developped project.

myMovieClip has been scaled and is nested into many movieclips which may have been scaled themselves

When I trace his width and height, it does not give me the right width and size: 
How can I get the absolute width and height ?
(the width and height it takes on the screen)

(a kind of **localToGlobalWidth** function)

regards

Comment: Please either accept an answer, or create your own (and accept it as the answer) so this question can be cataloged as answered.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `getBounds` method of a display object to get the bounds (actual width/height and position) relative to whatever display object you pass to the method as an argument.  ([doucmentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getBounds()))

```
myScaledObj.getBounds(stage);  //would return a rectangle of where on the stage the display object is.
```

The `width` and `height` property of the returned rectangle would be what you'd use.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how many times it's been scaled, and by how much it's being scaled? In that case, you could trace the width * the scaling, for example:

mc1 has a width of 100, and is being scaled by 2:

```
mc1.scaleX = 2;
trace (mc1.width*2);
```

**Extra information:** if it's being scaled by a variable, replace 2 with the variable name.
This method should work even if it's being scaled multiple times, by using a variable to pile up the scaling:

```
var scaler1:int = 2;
var scaler2:int = 7;
var scalePiler:int = scaler1*scaler2;
mc1.scaleX = scalePiler;
trace (mc1.width*scalePiler);
```

Hope I helped and covered all possibilities, good luck with your program! ^^

Comment: Your code actually will not give you the desired output.  Unless overridden, a display object's `.width` will reflect its own scaled value. **example:** if `mc1` is natively 100px wide, and you've scaled it to 2, `trace(mc1.width)` will output `200` - `trace(mc1.width * mc1.scaleX)` will output `400`.

Comment: From what I understood from the question, scaling the display object won't correctly output the new scaled width, but will output the original width, so, **in your example:** `trace(mc1.width)` will output 100, and  not 200, and so the next output will be 200, the desired output. Sorry if I'm wrong as I haven't tried it myself, but that's just what the question says :s

Comment: I don't mean to be rude or arrogant, but you are wrong.  Please try it and find that out. The issue is that the parents of the object are scaled, and naturally (by design) when you trace `mc1.width` is does not include any parent scaling (only it's own)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the parent-child part, I thought it was a general problem. My bad :s